# Find Key index in a rotated sorted array using binary sort?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

here in this code i am facing issues regarding my output of find the correct index for the key. the output of pivot element is correct but i was unable for find the error in the key index part of my code . can some debug it for me please or at least tell me where i was doing it wrong.

this is a code of me trying to find the index of key element in a sorted rotated array and my approach is as follows first i have to find the pivot element than i compare the size of element at pivot index and size of key element if the size is greater than pivot and less the size of array than i binary search between pivot and ( n -1 ) : which the last index of array . and if the size is small than i search between 0th index and pivot index.

so correct me where i am wrong.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int getPivot ( int arr[] , int size){

    int start =0;
    int end = size-1;

    int mid = start + ( end - start)/2;
    while( start < end ){
        if( arr[mid] > arr[0]){
            start = mid +1;
        }
        else{
            end = mid;
        }
        mid = start + ( end - start )/2;

    }
    return end;
}

int binarySearch ( int arr[] , int size , int s , int e , int key){

    int start = s;
    int end = e;
    int mid = s+( e-s )/2;
    while ( start <= end ){
        if( arr[mid] == key){
            return mid; 
        }
        else if ( arr[mid] > key ){
            end = mid -1;
        }
        else{
            start = mid +1;
        }
        mid = start+( end - start )/2;
    }
    return start ;
}

int main(){

    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;

    int arr[n];
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    int pivot = getPivot( arr , n);
    cout<<" the index of Pivot element is : "<<pivot<<endl;

    
    if( k >= arr[pivot] && k<= arr[n-1] ){
        cout<<" the index of the key is : " <<binarySearch( arr , n , pivot , ( n-1) , k)<<endl;
    }
    else{

        cout<<" the index of the key is : " <<binarySearch( arr , n , 0 , (pivot-1) , k)<<endl;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "rotated sorted array" and/or provide some sample input with expected output?

Comment: Some things that are completely wrong: "#include<bits/stdc++.h>", 
"using namespace std;", Using C-style arrays wit decayed pointer as paramter, using VLA (Variable Length Array)

Comment: *"the output of pivot element is correct but i was unable for find the error in the key index part of my code"* -- maybe you cannot find the error because the output is correct? What makes you think there is an error?

Comment: Array Rotation simply means shifting the array elements to the left or right of the array by specified positions. An array can be rotated to the left(clockwise) or to the right (anti-clockwise) to the given number of position . eg arr[5] ={ 1,2,3,4,5 } this is sorted array now if i did this arr[5] = { 5,1,2,3,4 } i just rotated the last index element to the 0th index . now it becomes rotated sotred array .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looked supsicous:

`int mid = s+( e-s )/2;`

It's not using modulo arithmetic correctly.  There's confusion of comparing `arr[mid]` with normalized vs. unnormalized coordinates and how that applies to recomputing start and end on each iteration of the binary search loop.  You want `start` and `end` to be recomputed in the "normalized" space, but `mid` needs to be adjusted for the pivot index value.

This also looked suspicious int `main`:

```
   if( k >= arr[pivot] && k<= arr[n-1] ){
        cout<<" the index of the key is : " <<binarySearch( arr , n , pivot , ( n-1) , k)<<endl;
    }
    else{

        cout<<" the index of the key is : " <<binarySearch( arr , n , 0 , (pivot-1) , k)<<endl;
    }
```

If I understand the problem correctly, the algorithm takes in a sorted array that could be rotated.  Where the input read from stdin could be something like the following:

```
10 4                        // n = 10, key=4
9 10 11 12 13 1 2 3 4 5     // the sorted rotated array
```

So in the above example if `key==4`, then we want to return `8` as the index since `array[8] == 4`

Here's a cleaned up version of your code.  The main changes are this:

1. Use the correct header includes
2. Removed the variable length array and replaced with std::vector.
3. Fixed the bug in binarySearch. Also, the `e` parameter isn't actually needed with this fix, so I removed that.
4. binarySearch will return `-1` if the element can't be found instead of `start`
5. Fixed `main` to just call `binarySearch` with the size and pivot index in a consistent way. No need to have two versions of calling it. Nor do you need to explicitly pass the end index.
6. `getPivot` had some bugs in it too. So I fixed that with similar modulo arithmetic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int getPivot(int arr[], int size) {

    int start = 0;
    int end = size - 1;

    if (size <= 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    while (start <= end)
    {
        int len = end - start + 1;
        int prev = (start + size - 1) % size;
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        if (arr[start] < arr[prev])
        {
            return start;
        }

        if (arr[start] <= arr[mid])
        {
            start = mid+1;
        }
        else
        {
            end = mid;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

int binarySearch(int arr[], int size, int pivot, int key) {

    int start = 0;           // start and end are in the "normalized" index space
    int end = size - 1;
    while (start <= end) {

        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        int actualMid = (pivot + mid) % size;  // actualMid is the denomalized conversion of mid using modulo arithmetic

        if (arr[actualMid] == key) {
            return actualMid;
        }
        else if (arr[actualMid] > key) {
            end = mid - 1;     // adjust end in normalized index space
        }
        else {
            start = mid + 1;   // adjust start in normalized index space
        }
    }
    return -1;
}


int main() {

    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;

    std::vector<int> arr(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    int pivot = getPivot(arr.data(), n);

    cout << " the index of Pivot element is : " << pivot << endl;
    cout << " the index of the key is : " << binarySearch(arr.data(), n, pivot, k) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Updated with a fix for `getPivot`

Comment: thanks it worked and it is easy to understand as well .

Comment: @ACID - I updated the implementation of getPivot again with what I think is a bug fix. The calculation of `prev`.

Answer (score 0):

## Index Retrieval in Rotated Sorted Arrays using Binary Search Algorithm in Java

---

> **pseudo-code flow for the Binary Search algorithm:**

---

1. Initialize ans variable to -1.
2. Set startIndex to 0 and endIndex to size - 1.
3. Calculate midIndex as the average of startIndex and endIndex.
4. Enter a loop while startIndex is less than endIndex.
5. Check if the element at midIndex is equal to the key:

   - If true, assign midIndex to ans and return ans.
6. Check if the element at midIndex is greater than the first element of the array and the key is within the range of the first element and the element at midIndex:

   - If true, update endIndex to midIndex - 1.
   - If false, update startIndex to midIndex + 1.
7. Recalculate midIndex as the average of the updated startIndex and endIndex.
8. Repeat steps 5 to 7 until the condition in the while loop is no longer satisfied.

9.Return the value of ans, which represents the index of the key if found, or -1 if not found.

> **The Iterative Approach**

```
public int findKey(int[] arr, int size, int key){
        int ans = -1;
        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = size - 1;
        int midIndex = startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex) / 2;
        while (startIndex<=endIndex){

            if(arr[midIndex] == key){
                ans = midIndex;
                return ans;
            } else if (arr[midIndex] > arr[0] && (key >= arr[0] && key < arr[midIndex])) {
                endIndex = midIndex - 1;
            }else {
                startIndex = midIndex + 1;
            }

            midIndex = startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex) / 2;
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Discover Comprehensive Solution Here [https://github.com/Amir36036/ds/blob/array/src/main/java/org/ds/array/FIndKeyINRotatedSortedArray.java](https://Discover%20Comprehensive%20Solution%20Here%20https://github.com/Amir36036/ds/blob/array/src/main/java/org/ds/array/FIndKeyINRotatedSortedArray.java)